# check if text of child element within div matches string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to check if the content of the #inner3-sub

inside of #inner3  is equal to a given string. If so, do something - else, do something else.

```
$('#inner3').on("click",function(){
  if($(this).html() === randomQuestion.actualAnswer){
    $('.container').css("background-color","#0dd913");
  }else{
    $('.container').css("background-color","#e7170d");
  }
});
```

I have a feeling that the problem resides within the $(this).html() selector but I do not know how to advance from this point.

For reference, I want to select the string value of randomQuestion.answer[i].

```
$('#inner2').append("<div id='inner3' class='animated bounceInUp'>" + "<p id='inner3-sub'>" + randomQuestion.answers[i] + "</p>" + "</div>");
```

[edit] for those who want to see everything, look at these pastebins

js -> https://pastebin.com/aMZdDLei
html -> https://pastebin.com/xLijSzsY

Comment: You need to ensure that the dynamically created elements get the onClick event handler attached to them once they become part of the DOM. Otherwise you can get the text of any HTML node with .text();

Comment: `this` refers to the element that the event was placed on @MattNewelski

Comment: I absolutely agree @EKW - I have modified my answer to contain only the relevant part.

Comment: to match text you need to pull text not html; use .text() not .html() of jquery api.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as you are creating dynamic controls better if you bind event on document or body, and search for selector on click event (of course this will be done by jquery itself);
also you need to trim the content and take text not html.

```js
$('body').on('click','#inner3',function(event){
  if($(event.target).text().trim() === 'vvf'){
     $('.container').css("background-color","#0dd913");
  }else{
    $('.container').css("background-color","#e7170d");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <p id="inner1">abc</p>
  <p id="inner2">des</p>
  <p id="inner3">vvf</p>
  <p id="inner4">kk</p>
<div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`$(this).html()` will, as you could expect, return the **html** of `#inner3`. If you want to get the **text** of `#inner3-sub` you can access it thusly:

```
$("#inner3-sub").text()
```

Comment: it is possible to do a specific search in jquery. By that i mean can i do something along the lines of: $(this '#inner3-sub').text(). I ask this because I will have 2-3 #inner3 elements created per run. I know I should use classes for non unique elements but thats besides the point

Comment: Yes, you can do `$(this).find("#inner3-sub").text()`

Comment: Are you making sure to add the event listener **after** you create the elements?

Comment: ya the #inner3 elements are created on a click event prior to all of this

Comment: @cerrach you need to add the click listener to #inner3 inside of the click event when it is created.

Comment: can you clarify a little more? click listener as in another jquery.on("click",function(){});?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `text()` method instead of `html()`. And if there is any whitespace in text of the `#inner3` then you need to use `$.trim()` method.

```
$('#inner3').on("click", function() {
    var currentText = $(this).text(),
        trimmedText = $.trim(currentText);
    if (trimmedText == randomQuestion.actualAnswer) {
        $('.container').css("background-color", "#0dd913");
    } else {
        $('.container').css("background-color", "#e7170d");
    }
});
```

Comment: i will try this. should there be var before trimmedText

Comment: No need to use var again because there is a comma after `$(this).text()` that is continuing line.

Comment: still nothing :(

Answer (score -1):

Since `#inner3` is dynamically created, you should use [delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/).
and use `.find()` to target the right element.

```
$('#inner2').on("click", "#inner3", function(){   // <-- use delegation on a static parent
  var currentText = $(this).find("#inner3-sub").text().trim();  // <-- use .find()
  if (currentText == randomQuestion.actualAnswer) {
    $('.container').css("background-color", "#0dd913");
  } else {
    $('.container').css("background-color", "#e7170d");
  }
});
```

So `#inner3` is delegated *(has the "responsability")* to handle the events occuring on its child `#inner2`, may it be present or not when the handler was declared and/or modified afterward.